# Accessing Ruby Threads

Tags: ruby

Probably not even a valid question but how can I see what this block contains:

```
spec = Thread.current[:spec]
print spec # gives => #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x7f61991d90c8>
```

Can I see any of the methods assigned to this or whatever is in it?

If more context is needed, I'm trying to understand what spec is doing here in function here but not being used anywhere (at least directly)

https://github.com/amfranz/rspec-hiera-puppet/blob/master/lib/rspec-hiera-puppet/puppet.rb#L7

Comment: how about `spect.inspect`

Comment: that seems to show its properties. Any idea on how I can actually access them?

Comment: You'd have to call `spec.propertyyouwant`. You could also try `spec.propertytoaccess.to_s` if you just wanted to see it.

Comment: ah! I was trying to access it like a hash. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view properties do:

```
spec.inspect
```

If you want to access those properties:

```
spec.propertyyouwant
```